# Combine multiple lines until character sequence

Tags: text-processing, newlines

Trying to combine multiple lines if it doesn't have an end of message string.  Would also like to remove the prefix on all but the first line.

Input:

```
b929e3e1-29db this is a long message that
abc074df-48a1 is continued onto multiple
dfd4c683-ab48 lines#EOM
ff513a72-570d this is a short message#EOM
980d10aa-bbed another short message#EOM
```

Output:

```
b929e3e1-29db this is a long message that is continued onto multiple lines
ff513a72-570d this is a short message
980d10aa-bbed another short message
```

Ideally using common tools available via command line. (ex: awk, sed)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Perl script treating "#EOM" as End-of-Paragraph, springs to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `awk`<sup>1</sup>

```
gawk -vRS='#EOM\n' '{gsub(/\n[[:xdigit:]-]+/,"");} {$1=$1} 1' file.txt
```

- set the record separator to `#EOM` followed by a newline
- remove sequences of hex digits and hyphens preceded by newlines; this retains the initial sequence of each record since its newline was eaten by the previous RS
- re-assign a field `$1=$1` to force the record to be re-evaluated with default output separators
- print the record (because `1` is true)

Testing

```
$ gawk -vRS='#EOM\n' '{gsub(/\n[[:xdigit:]-]+/,"");} {$1=$1} 1' file.txt
b929e3e1-29db this is a long message that is continued onto multiple lines
ff513a72-570d this is a short message
980d10aa-bbed another short message
```

<sup>1</sup>. it doesn't appear to work with `mawk`, for reasons I don't understand (even after replacing `+` by `\{1,\}` and various other tweaks)

Comment: It seems to work fine here with `mawk 1.3.4 20141206`.  FWIW.

Comment: @SatoKatsura thanks - seems mine is 1.3.3

Comment: It's the `[:xdigit:]` that doesn't work, `[a-f0-9-]+` works with `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996` (rather hideously old, that).